# Создание меню в футере wordpress

Tags: wordpress, link

Добрый день. Прошу помощи. Каким образом можно создать меню в футере страницы (чуть выше копирайта). Нужно вида: "Главная  |  блабла  |  блабла ". Впринципе обычной вставкой html-кода в footer.php меня устраивает. Но очень критично чтобы ссылки были не синего цвета. Как это можно сделать? Пробовал играться с link="цвет" но как были синими так и остались.

```
<html>
<body link="red" vlink="#cecece" alink="#ff0000" bgcolor="black">
<p style="text-align: center; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; font-size:14px; ">
<h4>
    <span style="color: #696969;">
        <a href="http://localhost/site/">На главную</a>  |  
        <a href="http://localhost/site/%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8/">О компании</a>  |  
        <a href="http://localhost/site/%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8/%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/">Раскрытие информации</a>  |  
        Закупки  |  
        <a href="http://localhost/site/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8c%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0/">Вакансии</a>  |  
        <a href="mailto:info@broker-sb.ru">Обратная связь</a>   |  
        <a href="http://localhost/site/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b/">Контакты</a>
    </span>
</h4>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно сделать быстро и ничего не гуглить, то

```
<a href="http://localhost/site/" style="color: #696969;">На главную</a>
```

Если долго и правильно, то, по-хорошему, вам нужно научиться использовать вынесенный во внешние файлы `css` для оформления страниц. Заодно поинтересуйтесь понятием семантичности кода, чтобы понимать, почему не стоит вкладывать заголовки в параграфы.